# Dynamics CRM report rendering issue (open up in a new tab)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

If i open an report in CRM 2015 with "run Report on selected report" the following happens:

1. report dialog window appears (loading)
2. new browser tab opens
3. report load into the new browser tab
4. report dialog window is still loading (endless)

So my problem is, that the Report renders in a new tab istead of the dialog window, but why?

Screenshot from new Tab & Dialog:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a custom button to launch the report?

Comment: No, i just open them via CRM: I select an entry -> "run Report" -> "Run on Current Record" -> "Name of the Report"